# Passing a value from child window to parent

Tags: asp.net, javascript, parameter-passing

Here is my scenario: i have a parent web page, in my javascript code I open a new window. This new window is a server-side aspx page. This child page needs to save some data in the database, and after saving it returns an ID. Now, I need to pass this ID from the child server page to the parent's javascript.

Essentially I need the child server code to trigger:
1) return the value to the javascript code of the parent page
2) close itself

What would be the acceptable way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable in the parent page:

```
var dbID;
```

When the DB call returns from the opened window, place this in the opened window's load event (or ready event if using jquery or another framework):

```
window.opener.dbID = <%= newID %> 
// or whatever your framework's technique is for this :-)
window.close();
```

You can also call a global function on the parent as well using the same technique.

On "parent" page:

```
function handleNewDBID(dbID) { alert("lookit me, i got an ID! " + dbID); }
```

And on the opened window:

```
window.opener.handleNewDBID(<%=newID%>);
```

Comment: How do i distinguish that "when the DB call returns from the opened window" in Jquery? Of course i can all ways check if newID is null..is that what you meant?

Comment: Modified answer to show using a global function.  Your JQuery code can live inside of that.  (I don't think there's an easier way to do this without making the function global.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the child window AND assuming your parent window has object *childResult*:

```
window.opener.childResult = "yourIdHere";
```